# Edit git commit to remove files before pushing?

Tags: git

Hello I've made a git commit (but haven't pushed) but it accidentally contains some bulky files I'd like to remove. All I want is to do a proper commit and push without the bulky files. (I'll manually move them out of the git tracked directory. )

I've seen some suggestions to use git reset --hard HEAD^ which I would assume would just move the commit pointer back but that nearly caused me to lose work so I want to be a bit more careful and get something that is confirmed not to cause data loss.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s the most recent commit, you can use `git commit --amend` to amend the commit before pushing, after staging the  removals.

- If you’ve already moved the files, Git should recommend the right command to you when you run `git status`: `git rm`.
- To stage the removal without doing anything to the files in the working tree yet, use `git rm --cached`.

```
git rm --cached path/to/bulky-file-1 path/to/bulky-file-2
git commit --amend
```

Comment: What if it is not the most recent commit?